# HP Recover command promt not showing up

Tags: windows, bootloader, recover

Today I was removing Ubuntu from my sister's pc (don't ask why it was on there ;P) and it said to delete the Ubuntu partition. I deleted the right one, and I put my HP Recovery disk in, but there's no option to open a command prompt, so I could enter: bootrec /fixmbr and bootrec /fixboot . Any help would be appreciated. I just need to open up the command prompt. Here's a picture of my recovery screen. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnkLb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the Windows recovery disk you are searching for and not HP(based on the commands).

When you boot into your Windows Recovery Disk you have to choose the "Troubleshot" option first. There you'll have an option to open a command prompt. See this [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/) for windows 7, 8 or 10

I'm sorry I'm quit new so I couldn't post this as a comment